# So in c# int has no sync block index and no reference to the type object. How does the CLR know what ToString() method to launch?

Tags: c#, reference, stack

All primitive types override ToString() and other methods (like == operator), but how does the CLR know which method to call, if it has no pointer to the type object? For primitive types, if I understood it correctly, there is no Sync block index as well as no reference to the type object - only the value held in stack.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: .Net is Just In Time Compiled.... thats to say the compiler has complete control of how the IL is emitted and the jitter jits it. All the information is there to accomplish this. Though I am wondering why you are worried about it. If you want to know the details, I suggest using something like https://sharplab.io/ or one of the many IL inspectors

Comment: What do you mean by "primitive types"? Are you thinking in terms of Java concepts?

Comment: `as well as no reference to the type object` https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTd2AHbAEwBALwF09ANxdu1ACIBDYAFMAKmAC2SggHMRBBcrWaAdADkA9gHcp2GTWkzk6AJwswxleYDKwAE59tdjYbO2onV20Pbz8AoJCaAF8cBKA== certainly suggests that the two values in the stack know their type.

Comment: @mjwills hey, ok the value types know their types (although I have no clue how), but then how does the compiler know which == operator to use? It kinda suggests the heap holds a copy of the Type object for the value type in question?

Comment: @MichaelRandall the reason why I am curios is because I am preparing for job interviews.

Comment: `It kinda suggests the heap holds a copy of the Type object for the value type in question?` Did you click the link I provided (check the IL on the right side)? Thinking in terms of Java's primitive types does not make sense in C#. C#'s notion of struct is **not** the same as Java's notion of primitive types.

Comment: @mjwills ok, I clicked the link. I see the IL. I still do not understand how the CLR knows to fetch System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32::ToString()? Why not ...byte.ToString()? How does the compiler differentiate the variables that only hold their value in the stack? And where does it hold the references to their methods?

Comment: `I still do not understand how the CLR knows to fetch` Because the variable is that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed value types have NO reference to the type object and NO SyncBlockIndex. That is why the compiler will BOX them when you call non-virtual methods like GetType() or MemberwiseClone(). Virtual methods like Equals(), GetHashCode() and ToString() are overridden and baked into value types, even into ones we create, and sealed, that is why they can be called without the reference to the type object. Moreover, if we override the methods ourselves and call base implementation of the method inside the override - the value type will always be boxed when calling our overridden method.

Source: Richter.

Answer (score 1):

For value types, there's no inheritance at play. This means that the type of the *variable* is sufficient to determine *exactly* which method is being called.

In turn, this means that the compiler will emit [`call`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call?view=netcore-3.1) instructions, rather than `callvirt`, which means the CLR doesn't need to use runtime type information to call the method.

Comment: What if the value type implements an interface (for my own curiosity)?

Comment: Hey, how can there be no inheritance if they all extend System.ValueType?

Comment: There's no inheritance in terms of `int i = <something>` means that `i` precisely contains an `int`, never a `long` or `byte`, etc. Which in turn means that later when the compiler sees `i.ToString()` it knows to emit a call precisely to `Int32`'s `ToString` method.